# Vue.js can't find element using querySelector

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a chat style form. So a user inputs their data and then uses the button within my template with the class of `continue-btn`.

As you can see when the `continue-btn` is pressed it uses the `nextStep` method which adds 1 to the `counter` data property.

Within my template I then use `v-if="counter >= 1"` to display the next section of the chat dialog and input field.

I am then trying to use scrollTop to automatically scroll the page to the new section with the id of `#conversation__tram-1`. I originally tried running this block of code just after the `counter` had been given a value of 1:

```
const container = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-" + this.counter);
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

This didn't work though because I'm guessing the `#conversation__tram-1` element hadn't been added to the DOM yet.

So for the sake of testing I tried wrapping it in a timeout function:

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    const container = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-" + this.counter);
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
  }, 3000);
```

However I am left with this error when trying this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
```

Here is my whole single vue file:

```
<template>

    <div id="conversation-app">
      <!-- <div v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.text }}
      </div> -->
      <div class="conversation__track">
        <div id="conversation__tram-0">
          <div class="conversation__item agent">
            <img src="/assets/cdn.annuityadvicecentre.dev/images/theme-f/michael-chat-agent.jpg" class="conversation__item-prof-img" alt="Michael Chat Agent" />
            <div class="conversation__item-content">
              <p>
                Hello my name is {{ agent }}, we'll compare the whole annuity market to bring you back the best annuity rates from the top providers for you. Let's get started, what's your name?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="conversation__item customer" id="title-fullname">
            <div class="conversation__item-content">
              <p>
                Hi {{ agent }}, my name is...
              </p>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <select id="title" class="field-title" name="payload[title]"><option value="mr">Mr</option><option value="mrs">Mrs</option><option value="miss">Miss</option><option value="ms">Ms</option></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                  <input v-model="customerName" id="full_name" class="field-full_name" name="payload[full_name]" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <transition name="fade">
          <div id="conversation__tram-1" v-if="counter >= 1">
            <div class="conversation__item agent">
              <img src="/assets/cdn.annuityadvicecentre.dev/images/theme-f/michael-chat-agent.jpg" class="conversation__item-prof-img" alt="Michael Chat Agent" />
              <div class="conversation__item-content">
                <p>
                  Thanks {{ firstName }}, nice to meet you. To process your instant quote please can I have your Pension Value?
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="conversation__item customer">
              <div class="conversation__item-content">
                <p>
                  Sure, my pension value is...
                </p>
                <input id="pension_value" class="field-pension_value" placeholder="£" pattern="\d*" name="payload[pension_value]" type="number">
                <div class="error-wrap error_pension_value is-hidden" data-format="<div class=&quot;error-text&quot;>:message</div>"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
        <div id="conversation__buttons">
          <button type="button" class="continue-btn"
          v-on:click="nextStep"
          >Continue&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'conversation-app',
  data () {
    return {
      agent: 'Brick',
      counter: 0,
      customerName: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextStep: function() {
      this.counter += 1;
      setTimeout(function(){
        const container = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-" + this.counter);
        container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
      }, 3000);

    },
  },
  computed: {
    firstName() {
      return this.customerName.split(' ')[0];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a good time to use arrow functions, as they preserve the context of `this`.

```
nextStep: function() {
  this.counter += 1;
  setTimeout(() => {
    const container = this.$el.querySelector("#conversation__tram-" + this.counter);
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
  }, 3000);
```

Altenatively, instead of the timeout you can use `Vue.nextTick` which is a more technically-correct way of doing this.

```
nextStep: function () {
  this.counter += 1
  this.$nextTick(() => { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks this example now allows me to select the element however it isn't scrolling to the bottom of the element. Any idea why? Nothing seems to happen with no errors.

Comment: I have also tried using `container.scrollTop = 0` for the sake of simplicity and this doesn't work either. I have used Vue.nextTick like you have mentioned.

Comment: Try `console.log`-ing out the values of `container.scrollTop` and `container.scrollHeight`, check to see what they are. Also make sure that the `#conversation__tram-x` element is the _actual_ element you want to scroll.

Comment: Yes that element is the one I'd like to scroll to. I have checked the values, `scrollTop` is equal to 0 and `scrollHeight` is equal to 296. If I console the `container` variable it is the element that I expect it to scroll to.

Comment: Wait, you expect it to scroll __to__ the `container` element? Currently you are trying to scroll the inner contents of the `container` element itself. If you want to scroll the `container` parent to show the `container` element, you will need to get it's parent element and scroll that.